# How do i import photos from a Lumia phone to El Capitan's Photos app?

Tags: photos.app

I plug my phone into my mac as I would with an iPhone, and indeed Photos says that it can find the device, however it doesn't show any photo thumbnails or give you any options to import the photos. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this soft :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/product/nokia-photo-transfer-for-mac/

> Use this software to transfer photos and videos between your Nokia
>   Lumia phone with Windows Phone 8 and your Mac computer or laptop with
>   Mac OS

After that you can import your photos (stored on your computer) by using Photos.

```
Photos -> File -> Import ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume this means that there's no way to get the photos to go directly into Photos.app then?

Comment: Photos can import from many devices... Perhaps there is no Lumia driver's in Photos... I didn't found any supported devices list.